# How can I put sin cos function into this RPN calculator

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXVAL 100
#define MAXOP 100
#define NUMBER '0'
#define BUFSIZE 100
#define sinn 'sin'

int sp = 0;
double val[MAXVAL];
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufp = 0;

double aatof(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);
int ggetop(char []);
int ggetch(void);
void unggetch(int);

int main()
{
    int type;
    double op2;
    int op3;
    char s[MAXOP];
    while ((type = ggetop(s)) != EOF)
    {

        switch (type)
        {
            case NUMBER:
                push(aatof(s));
                break;
            case '+':
                push(pop() + pop());
                break;
            case '*':
                push(pop() * pop());
                break;
            case '-': // negative number
                if (isdigit(ggetop(s))){
                    push(0-aatof(s));
                    break;}
            case '--': // minus
                op2 = pop();
                push(pop() - op2);
                break;
            case '/':
                op2 = pop();
                if (op2 != 0.0)
                    push(pop() / op2);
                else
                    printf("error: zero divisor\n");
                break;
            case '%':
                op3 = (int)pop();
                if (op3 != 0)
                    push((int)pop() % op3);
                else
                    printf("error: zero divisor\n");
                break;
            case 'sin':
                push(sin(pop()));
                break;
            case '\n':
                printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
                break;

            default:
                printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int ggetop(char s[])
{
    int i, c;
    while ((s[0] = c = ggetch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')


    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c))
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = ggetch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.')
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = ggetch()))
            ;

    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        unggetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}

int ggetch(void)
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void unggetch(int c)
{
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("unggetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}

double aatof(char s[])
{
    double val, power;
    int i, sign;
    for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); i++)
        ;
    sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-')
        i++;
    for (val = 0.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
        val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0');
    if (s[i] == '.')
        i++;
    for (power = 1.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
    {
        val = 10.0 * val + (s[i] - '0');
        power *= 10.0;
    }
    return sign * val / power;
}

void push(double f)
{
    if (sp < MAXVAL)
        val[sp++] = f;
    else
        printf("error: stack full, can't push %g\n", f);
}

double pop(void)
{
    if (sp > 0)
        return val[--sp];
    else
    {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

I am not sure how can I put the sin cos pow function into different cases. I've tried to use `isalpha()` in `ggetop(char s[])` and turn letters into integer but it doesn't seem to work. what I want to do is process the letter and give back the ASCII number, and add them into type. I wonder how to process the letters altogether at once and not individually.

```
if(isalpha(c)){
            s[++i] = c = ggetch();
            return c;}
```

are there other ways to add sin cos and pow functions into the programs?

Comment: `case '--'` will not work very well. `'--'` is a multi-character and their handling is implementation defined. And if `char` is a single byte on your system, how could it even store two characters? Same with `sin` (and supposedly `cos` if you want to add it). Start with single-letter function names, then refactor your code to be able to handle *strings*.

Comment: As for `-` for negation and `--` for subtraction, please spend some time to read more literature, tutorials and examples to learn how to handle `-` for *both*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: This is RPN, so it's not really possible to use `-` for both subtraction and negation.

Comment: ... unless you "fake" **x neg**  with **0 x sub**.

Comment: Then I suggest you use some other notation for negation, as subtraction is more common and is expected to be only a single `-`. Perhaps `n` for negation? Then when you have added support for strings and multi-character function names, perhaps `neg`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The '-' and '--' both work but the sin one doesn't, due to that they're letters? That's why I am quite confused cause apparently multi characters like '--' does work

Comment: @AutumnExp1: I don't see how the ggetop you pasted can work at all. What is the target of `if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')`?

Comment: (In the original, the target of that `if` statement was `return c`. Did you accidentally leave that out of the copy and paste?)

Comment: Also: `case '--'` will never match anything. Ever. But the `-` will be caught by `case '-':` and that will then fall through because the clause doesn't have a `break;` at the end. Sometimes falling through will produce the desired result. But concluding from that result that `case '--`:` is "working" is about on the same level as concluding that since you've never had a visit from a zombie, that leaving a garlic bulb outside your door keeps zombies away.